# Get ID of a page containing secondary loop in content

Tags: loop, post-meta, content

I am trying to get the ID (outside of loop) of a page which have a loop of another CPT within its content using a shortcode.

If I do a `print_r` of `get_queried_object()`, all I get the args used to register the CPT
If I `echo` `$post->ID` I get the ID of the last item in the secondary loop.
If I `echo` `get_queried_object_id()`, I get `0` all the time.

Here is the code I am currently using

```
function get_meta_values() {
    global $post;
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $queried_object ); //Returns args used to register the CPT
    echo '<br> $queried_object->ID: ' . $queried_object->ID; //Returns Nothing
    echo '<br>get_queried_object_id(): '. get_queried_object_id(); // Returns 0 all the time
    echo.'<br>PageID: ' . $post->ID; // Returns the ID of last item in the secondary loop
    echo '</pre>';

}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'get_meta_values' );
```

My goal is to get the ID of the page (where the shortcode is) to retrive some custom field values.

**EDIT:** I am using WooCommerce, but the shortcode that outputs the products is custom. I know I could bypass the issue by other means, but just curious why this is not working.

Comment: are you using `query_posts` in the shortcode? it sounds like you are overwriting the `$wp_query` global.

Comment: @Milo No, the simple `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` secondary loop .

Comment: Which template is this exactly. `get_queried_object()` should return the queried object regardless where it is used and should remain unchanged (*`query_posts` breaks this, and also using `$wp_query` as a local variuable*). The queried object ID is however `0`  when the current page being viewed is the homepage or an archive page. If it is a true page from which I understand, and you are sure you are not using `query_posts`, then you need to look at the plugins you are using. Try adding `add_action( 'wp_head', 'get_meta_values' ); ` and see what results you get there.

Comment: If the results are different between `wp_head` and `wp_footer`, you definitely have an instance of `query_posts` somewhere. If the results are the same, you have a serious issue somewhere with WordPress itself

Comment: If you have a functioning ***secondary loop*** that looks like this-- `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`-- then you are clobbering the main query somewhere.

Comment: @PieterGoosen The results of `$post->ID` changes if I hook the same callback on `wp_head` but the others remain same, now it echos the Post ID of the first item of CPT loop. I really don't understand why the `get_queried_object_id()` returns 0 (I know it returns 0 on homepage and archive pages, but this is not really a archive. A simple page that *acts* as a archive for a CPT.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Yeah, may be. But its a newly generated _S theme with almost no modification.

Comment: Something has been altered, the theme is doing something very wrong, or that is not a secondary loop. I don't think we can help until you can get better information.

Comment: Thinking abour this issue, a week or two ago I helped someone with the same thing, turned out that it was YOAST which caused the issue. Have you tried disabling plugins and switching themes. It is like @s_ha_dum also states,  something somewhere is altering something it should not. You should relly start by eliminating plugins and your theme here

Comment: try `wp_reset_query()` before accessing the queried object.

Answer (score 1):

As others figured already out: If you have third party plugins with custom queries, you'll have a bad day!

One solution might be caching your results.

**Template** (e.g.: page.php)

```
while (have_posts()): the_post();
    global $my_cached_data;
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    /* 
     * If you have single meta keys, this array_map function 
     * makes them easy to access; otherwise just use:
     *
     * $my_cached_data[$post_id] = get_post_meta( $post_id) 
     */
    $my_cached_data[$post_id] = array_map( 
        function( $a )
        { 
            return $a[0]; 
        }, 
        get_post_meta( $post_id) 
    );
endwhile;
```

**footer.php**

```
global $my_cached_data;
echo "<pre>".print_r($my_cached_data, true)."</pre>";
```

**Possible Result** (with Page ID 2 and 15 having the same post meta data)

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
        ["meta_key"]=>
    string(10) "meta_value"
        ["another_key"]=>
    string(10) "meta_value"
  }
  [15]=>
  array(2) {
        ["meta_key"]=>
    string(10) "meta_value"
        ["another_key"]=>
    string(10) "meta_value"
  }
}
```